# Large array into clusters using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [blog_id] => 1
            [site_id] => 1
            [domain] => www.my-domain.dch
            [path] => /another-blog-path/
            [spam] => 0
            [deleted] => 0
            [blogname] => Another Company
            [siteurl] => http://www.my-domain.dch/another-blog-path
        )

    ...

    [2340] => stdClass Object
        (
            [blog_id] => 28
            [site_id] => 1
            [domain] => www.my-domain.dch
            [path] => /my-blog-path/
            [spam] => 0
            [deleted] => 0
            [blogname] => Company Namy
            [siteurl] => http://www.my-domain.dch/my-blog-path
        )
)
```

What I am looking for is to create a new array that will cluster the huge one in the following form:

```
Array
(
    [Ano] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [blog_id] => 1
                [site_id] => 1
                [domain] => www.my-domain.dch
                [path] => /another-blog-path/
                [spam] => 0
                [deleted] => 0
                [blogname] => Another Company
                [siteurl] => http://www.my-domain.dch/another-blog-path
            ),
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [blog_id] => 2
                [site_id] => 1
                [domain] => www.my-domain.dch
                [path] => /another-user-blog-path/
                [spam] => 0
                [deleted] => 0
                [blogname] => Another User Company
                [siteurl] => http://www.my-domain.dch/another-user-blog-path
            ),
    )

    ...

    [Com] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [blog_id] => 28
                [site_id] => 1
                [domain] => www.my-domain.dch
                [path] => /my-blog-path/
                [spam] => 0
                [deleted] => 0
                [blogname] => Company Name
                [siteurl] => http://www.my-domain.dch/my-blog-path
            )
)
```

The basic idea I like to implement is to get the first three leters of the companies names, and all the companies that match the first three letters to be added as child of that array key.

Thus, in example, the companies with names `"Company Name"`, `"Commands and Order Company"`, `"Comparis Masters Company"` to become available under the path `$my_companies['Com'][idx]->blogname`.

**So, what is the best approach in order to use less resources from my server ?**

Sidenote, may be required to use another level, above the three letters, by using the initial company name as a first level of the clusters.

Comment: your expectation is an incorrect array. Keys should be unique however, you have `0` as key for two keys

Comment: Either I'm missing something or this is trivial... Iterate through the original array via `foreach` loop and construct the new data array. Let me know if you need a hand with coding it up.

Comment: @Guns Ok, I made the array by the hand, and I had an error (I will fix it now), but this is not the point :)

Comment: @dezlov I am looking for the best practice to follow, in order to spend less resources from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an example, you might need to handle special cases like lowercase or shorter than 3 `blogname`.

```
$values = array_reduce($array, function ($new, $value) {

    $index = substr($value->blogname, 0, 3);

    $new[$index][] = $value;

    return $new;

}, array());
```

Or using a `foreach`

```
$new = array();

foreach ($array as $value) {
    $index = substr($value->blogname, 0, 3);
    $new[$index][] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ternary search trie. An alternative approach is to use arrays for example:http://phpir.com/tag/trie.